# Grid View Items are displayed too small: Java Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am implementing a grid view in java Android Studio to show all the images from gallery into it. Everything works fine but my grid view items are being displayed very small. There is a lot of spacing left horizontally between columns unnecessarily which makes the items small. This is my **activity xml file having grid view**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ImportFromGallery">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.9">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.25">
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.003"
                android:background="#e1e1e1" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.747">

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/galleryViewGridView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:numColumns="3"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth">
                </GridView>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.003"
        android:background="#e1e1e1" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.097">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.8">
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.003"
                android:background="#e1e1e1" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.197">
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my **image view to be displayed in each item of grid view:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="1dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gridGalleryImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is **the output I am getting:**

[image]
**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**And this is the output I want:**

[image]

What could be the problem for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code for your Image View that you are inflating in your grid view items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="3dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gridGalleryImageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```